# "Вызвано исключение" в Visual Studio 2017 язык СИ

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

Есть код, редактирование существующей записи и внесение изменений в файл, успешно изменяю одну,"первую", запись, со следующего,"второго" изменения программа вылетает ,как я понимаю, в библиотеку ввода, вывода, и пишет " "название проекта" вызвал срабатывание точки останова ", к слову, в самом коде ошибку не показывает, не представляю как это исправить и даже с чего начать, буду очень благодарен, это курсовая работа,которую должен сдать через две недели, так что вопрос очень насущный, заранее благодарю за любые советы/варианты решения
Вот код этой функции :

```
void red()
{
    int f = 0, k, s,d1;
    if ((fp = fopen("dob.txt", "w+")) == NULL)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл!\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return;
    }
    vivod();
qwe:
    printf("\nВведите номер записи, которую хотите отредактировать: ");
    if (!scanf("%d", &k))
    {
        printf("Введите число:\n");
        getchar();
        goto qwe;
    }
    else if (k<i || k>i)
    {
        printf("Выбранного номера не существует, повторите ввод:\n");
        getchar();
        goto qwe;
    }
qqwe:
    while (f==0)
    {
        printf("1 - Редактировать номер договора\n");
        printf("2 - Редактировать год заключения договора\n");
        printf("3 - Редактировать месяц заключения договора\n");
        printf("4 - Редактировать день заключения договора\n");
        printf("5 - Редактировать тип кредита\n");
        printf("6 - Редактировать сумму выдаваемого кредита\n");
        printf("7 - Редактировать срок выдаваемого кредита\n");
        printf("8 - Редактировать номер филиала банка\n");
        printf("9 - Редактировать имя заёмщика\n");
        printf("10 - Редактировать фамилию заёмщика\n");
        printf("11 - Редактировать возраст заёмщика\n");
        printf("12 - Вернуться назад\n");
        if (!scanf("%d", &s))
        {
            printf("Введите число:\n");
            getchar();
            goto qqwe;
        }
        else if (s < 1 || s>12)
        {
            printf("Введите число от 1 до 12:\n");
            getchar();
            goto qqwe;
        }
        switch (s)
        {
        case 1:
        b:
            printf("Номер договора: ");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].number))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b;
            } fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number);  break;
        case 2:

        b1:
            printf("Год заключения договора: ");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].date.god))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b1;
            }
            else if (K[k].date.god < 1900 && K[k].date.god>2019)
            {
                printf("Введите подходящий год:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b1;
            }fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number); break;
        case 3:

        b2:
            printf("Месяц заключения договора: \n");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].date.month))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b2;
            }
            else if (K[k].date.month < 1 && K[k].date.month>12)
            {
                printf("Введите число от 1 до 12");
                getchar();
                goto b2;
            } fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number); break;

        case 4:
        b3:
            printf("День заключения договора: \n");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].date.day))
            {
                printf("Введите число:");
                getchar();
                goto b3;
            }
            else if (K[k].date.day < 1 && K[k].date.day>31)
            {
                printf("Введите число от 1 до 31:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b3;
            }fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number); break;
        case 5:
            printf("Введите тип кредита:\n");
            agai1:
            printf("1-Лизинг\n");
            printf("2-Факторинг\n");
            printf("3-Форфэтинг\n");
            if (!scanf("%d", &d1))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto agai1;
            }
            else if (d1 < 1 || d1>3)
            {
                printf("Введите число от 1 до 3");
                getchar();
                goto agai1;
            }
            switch (d1)
            {
            case 1:
                strcpy(K[i].type, "Лизинг");
                fprintf(fp, "Тип кредита - %s\n", K[k].type); break;
            case 2:
                strcpy(K[i].type, "Факторинг");
                fprintf(fp, "Тип кредита - %s\n", K[k].type); break;
            case 3:
                strcpy(K[i].type, "Форфэтинг");
                fprintf(fp, "Тип кредита - %s\n", K[k].type); break;
            }
            break;
        case 6:

        b4:
            printf("Сумма выдаваемого кредита: \n");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].sum))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b4;
            }fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number);
            break;
        case 7:

        b5:
            printf("Срок кредита в днях: \n");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].srok))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b5;
            }fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number);
            break;
        case 8:
        b6:
            printf("Номер филиала банка: \n");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].filial))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b6;
            }fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number);
            break;
        case 9:
            printf("Имя заёмщика: \n");
            scanf("%s", &K[k].info.name);
            fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number);
            break;
        case 10:

            printf("Фамилия заёмщика:\n");
            scanf("%s", &K[k].info.surname);
            fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number);
            break;
        case 11:

        b8:
            printf("Возраст заёмщика:\n");
            if (!scanf("%d", &K[k].info.age))
            {
                printf("Введите число:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b8;
            }
            else if (K[k].info.age < 18 && K[k].info.age>150)
            {
                printf("Введите подходящий возраст:\n");
                getchar();
                goto b8;
            }fprintf(fp, "Номер договора - %d  ", K[k].number);
            break;
        case 12:f = 1;
            break;
        default:
        {
            printf("Ошибка ввода. Попробуйте еще раз.\n");
            system("PAUSE");
            if (f != 0) break;
            system("cls");
        }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

[image: то что показывает при выкидывании из программы]

Comment: В стеке вызовов посмотрите в какой строке вашей программы вызывается исключение.

Comment: А не подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать

Comment: Правое нижнее окно на вашем скриншоте, открываете закладку "Стек вызовов" и смотрите всю цепочку вызовов.